# How to write a unit test for this method bool TryGetValue(string key, out byte[] value);

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, extension-methods

I have an extension method Get(); but I cannot write extension method test. My extension method alternately use TryGetMethod(), so I want to write unit test for this method. But I don't understand what is **out byte[] value**
Here is my main extension method

```
public ResponseModel GetResponse()
    {
        if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.IsAvailable
            && httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Keys.Contains(nameof(_responseModel)))
        {
            var response = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Get<ResponseModel>(nameof(_responseModel));
            httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Remove(nameof(_responseModel));
            
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

i cannot write proper way for this line

> var response = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Get(nameof(_responseModel));

plesase help me, advance thank you

Comment: Here is the `out` documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to test. Which class does your TryGetValue method belong to? What type are you extending?

Comment: Why do you want to test the session? It's already been tested by microsoft.

Comment: I want to test **GetResponse** Method . And I used a extension method **Get()** that I cannot write test. my extension method indirectly user **TryGetValue()** so I want to write unit test for TryGetValue

Comment: Not understand why and where did you use the TryGetValue. But for your error, you need custom SessionExtensions to make `Session.Set<T>` work. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0#set-and-get-session-values-1